# Seeking explanation forEach javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working with the following array of objects and I am trying to run a function with forEach. However, I don't want to destroy the original `tbl1`. Hence, I made a copy of `tbl1` in `tbl2` and I am running `forEach` on `tbl2`.

What surprises me, if I run a `forEach` on `tbl2` so that I can preserve the `tbl1` structure, it also takes place in `tbl1` which I don't want.

```js
const tbl1 = [{ "Month": 1, "Value": 100 }, { "Month": 2, "Value": 200 }, { "Month": 3, "Value": 300 }]

const tbl2 = tbl1;

tbl2.forEach(
    (d)=>{d.newCol=d.Month*152;});

console.log(tbl1,tbl2);
```

Is it possible to run `forEach` on a `copy` table without destroying the `source`  table?

Comment: You're likely surprised to learn that `tbl2 = tbl1` does not make a copy.  Rather, now `tbl2` is a variable that refers to the same array that `tbl1` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `map`

```js
const tbl1 = [{ "Month": 1, "Value": 100 }, { "Month": 2, "Value": 200 }, { "Month": 3, "Value": 300 }]

const tbl2 = tbl1.map(d => {
  return {
   ...d,
   newCol: d.Month*152
  }
})


console.log(tbl1,tbl2);
```

If you want to do a deep copy you should use  `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`

```js
const tbl1 = [{ "Month": 1, "Value": 100 }, { "Month": 2, "Value": 200 }, { "Month": 3, "Value": 300 }]

const tbl2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tbl1));

tbl2.forEach(
    (d)=>{d.newCol=d.Month*152;});

console.log(tbl1,tbl2);
```

Comment: Many thanks for showing `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`.

Answer (score 2):

That is because when you write `const tbl2 = tbl1;`, it doesn't clone the array, rather takes a reference to the original. So when you modify the the reference, the original gets modified as well.

Comment: Wow I did not know that. Thanks. What is a convenient way take `tbl1` in a var/const where it does not refer to the original structure anymore and if I run `forEach` it does not hurt the source table.

Comment: @smpa01 use `map` to deep copy/clone.